# How to find the position of a projectile going on the path of an ellipses

Tags: geometry

For a game i am developing i am trying to create a projectile that goes along the path of an ellipses, I'm frankly not the best at math's and asked my friend whom is doing a level math's if he could help me with it and he gave me this equation

$$(x-j)^2 + 2(y-i)^2 = r^2$$

(Sorry i have no idea how to format it correctly here if its wrong)

this creates an ellipses but i would like to know how i can find the values of x and y in this equation to use them for the position of my projectile in my game, or if this equation is totally wrong

EDIT: the projectile is supposed to act like a boomerang coming from the player to a certain point then back to the player after reaching that point, I would like for it to decelerate more the closer it gets to the point until accelerating back to the player

Comment: To format your equation, surround it with dollar signs.

Comment: That equation describes an ellipse centred at $(i,j)$ whose width is $1/\sqrt2$ its height. You should explain how do you want that projectile to move: with constant speed, or else?

Comment: You select an x and than compute the y.

Comment: You could use, for simplification, the x value to determine acceleration rate.